# Como eu posso comparar uma variável dentro de uma lista de listas lendo/alterando o conteúdo delas em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo

```py
board=[['1','2','3'],
       ['4','5','6'], 
       ['7','8','9']]

p_move = input('Enter your move: ')) # p_move = '4'
for row in board:
    for column in row:
        if p_move == board[row][column]: # '4' == board[1][0]
           board[row][column] = 'O' # board[1][0] = 'O'

(TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está confundindo o **índice de uma linha** com **o elemento** (lista) **de uma linha**.

No seu loop:

```
for row in board:
    for column in row:
        if p_move == board[row][column]:
```

`board` é uma lista de listas, portanto ao iterar sobre ele, cada elemento (`row`) será uma lista.

Ao escrever `board[row]`, você efetivamente escreve (para a primeira iteração) `board[[['1','2','3']]`, causando o erro que você vê.

Uma maneira simples de corrigir isso é usar `range` e `len`, para aí sim iterar sobre uma sequência numérica:

```
board=[['1','2','3'],
       ['4','5','6'], 
       ['7','8','9']]

n_rows = len(board)
n_cols = len(board[0])  # assumimos que board é quadrada

p_move = input('Enter your move: ')
for row in range(n_rows):
    for column in range(n_cols):
        if p_move == board[row][column]:
           board[row][column] = 'O'
```

Comment: Obrigado eu estava tentando anteriormente usar algo assim

`python

for row in len(board):
    for column in len(row):`